# JAXB unexpected element error while unmarshaling

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, wsdl, jax-ws

I would be very grateful if someone finds a solutions for my problem...

While invoking a web method from my WebService I've got following error:

> [com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 223; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"sport"). Expected elements are <{}mostFavored>,<{}teamA>,<{}teamB>,<{http://sdl.ws.lsep.lskings.com/}scoring>,<{http://sdl.ws.lsep.lskings.com/}sport>,<{}gameId>,<{http://sdl.ws.lsep.lskings.com/}gameScoring>]

I wonder why the message contains element "sport" and why it isn't matched to the <{http://sdl.ws.lsep.lskings.com/}sport>. I think that this is related to the namespaces but I couldn't manage to resolve that problem and I've been stuck for 2 nights so far...

I am using JBossWS tool to generate client web services and everything is deployed on JBoss 7.1.1 (but I don't think that this is relevant). Please give me at least any clue :)

Here is GameScoring class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`GAMESCORING`")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(name = "GameScoring", propOrder = { "gameScoringId", "scoring", "finished", "startTime", "stopTime",
    "tiebreak" })
public class GameScoring implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "game_scoring_id")
private long gameScoringId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "scoring")
private List<GamePeriod> periods;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "scoring_id")
private Scoring scoring;

private boolean finished;

private Date startTime;

private Date stopTime;

private GamePeriod tiebreak;

public GameScoring() {
    super();
}
```

and the same class generated on the client side:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "GameScoring", propOrder = {
"gameScoringId",
"scoring",
"finished",
"startTime",
"stopTime",
"tiebreak"
})

public class GameScoring {

protected long gameScoringId;
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://sdl.ws.lsep.lskings.com/")
protected Scoring scoring;
protected boolean finished;
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar startTime;
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar stopTime;
protected GamePeriod tiebreak;
+ getters/setters
```

How I invoke web service methods:

```
GameManagerService gm_service = new GameManagerService();
GameManagerPortType gm_port = gm_service.getGameManagerPort();
com.lskings.lsep.ws.sdl.Game game = gm_port.getMostFavored();
```

Here web service SEI:

```
@WebService(name = "GameManagerPortType")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use = Use.LITERAL)
public interface GameManagerEndpoint {

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "success")
public boolean addGame(
        @WebParam(name = "sportId") String sportId,
        @WebParam(name = "leagueId") String leagueId,
        @WebParam(name = "scoringId") String scoringId,
        @WebParam(name = "participantHomeId") long participantHomeId,
        @WebParam(name = "participantAwayId") long participantAwayId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "success")
public boolean deleteGame(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "exists")
public boolean exists(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "game")
public Game getGame(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "gameList")
public List<Game> getGamesForLeague(@WebParam(name = "leagueId") long leagueId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "gameList")
public List<Game> search(@WebParam(name = "query") String query);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "gameList")
public List<Game> getGamesForSport(@WebParam(name = "sportId") long sportId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "game")
public Game getMostFavored();

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "success")
public boolean setMostFavored(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "gamePeriods")
public List<GamePeriod> getPeriods(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "gamePeriodsWithTiebreaks")
public List<GamePeriod> getPeriodsWithTiebreaks(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "gameScore")
public int[] getScore(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "periodActions")
public List<GameAction> getPeriodActions(@WebParam(name = "periodId") long periodId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "allActions")
public List<GameAction> getAllActions(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "gameTimer")
public String getGameTimer(@WebParam(name = "gameId") long gameId);

}
```

full stack trace:

http://pastebin.com/9pfCNFcw

Game.java - server side

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "`GAME`")
 @XmlRootElement
 @XmlType(name = "Game", propOrder = { "gameId", "sport", "mostFavored" })
 public class Game implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1564911377701558631L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "game_id")
private long gameId;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "sport_id")
private Sport sport;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "scoring_id")
private Scoring scoring;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "game_scoring_id")
private GameScoring gameScoring;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "teamA_id")
private Participant teamA;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "teamB_id")
private Participant teamB;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "league_id")
private League league;

@Column(name = "most_favored")
private boolean mostFavored;

public Game() {
    super();
}

public Game(Sport sport, Scoring scoring, Participant teamA, Participant teamB) {
    this(sport, scoring, teamA, teamB, null);
}

public Game(Sport sport, Scoring scoring, Participant teamA, Participant teamB, League league) {
    super();
    this.sport = sport;
    this.scoring = scoring;
    this.teamA = teamA;
    this.teamB = teamB;
    this.league = league;
    this.mostFavored = false;

    LinkedList<GamePeriod> periods = new LinkedList<GamePeriod>();

    this.gameScoring = new GameScoring();

    Period p = scoring.getPeriods().get(0);
    GamePeriod gp = new GamePeriod(p, gameScoring);
    periods.add(gp);
    gp.generateParents(true);

    gameScoring.setPeriods(periods);
    gameScoring.setScoring(scoring);
}

public Sport getSport() {
    return sport;
}

@XmlTransient
public Scoring getScoring() {
    return scoring;
}

@XmlTransient
public Participant getTeamA() {
    return teamA;
}

@XmlTransient
public Participant getTeamB() {
    return teamB;
}

@XmlTransient
public GameScoring getGameScoring() {
    return gameScoring;
}

public void setSport(Sport sport) {
    this.sport = sport;
}

public void setScoring(Scoring scoring) {
    this.scoring = scoring;
}

public void setGameScoring(GameScoring gameScoring) {
    this.gameScoring = gameScoring;
}

public void setTeamA(Participant teamA) {
    this.teamA = teamA;
}

public void setTeamB(Participant teamB) {
    this.teamB = teamB;
}

public long getGameId() {
    return gameId;
}

public void setGameId(long gameId) {
    this.gameId = gameId;
}

@XmlTransient
public League getLeague() {
    return league;
}

public void setLeague(League league) {
    this.league = league;
}

public boolean isMostFavored() {
    return mostFavored;
}

public void setMostFavored(boolean mostFavored) {
    this.mostFavored = mostFavored;
}

}
```

Game.java - client side:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Game", propOrder = {
"gameId",
"sport",
"mostFavored"
})
public class Game {

protected long gameId;
 //    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://sdl.ws.lsep.lskings.com/")
protected Sport sport;
protected boolean mostFavored;

/**
 * Gets the value of the gameId property.
 * 
 */
public long getGameId() {
    return gameId;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the gameId property.
 * 
 */
public void setGameId(long value) {
    this.gameId = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the sport property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Sport }
 *     
 */
public Sport getSport() {
    return sport;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the sport property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link Sport }
 *     
 */
public void setSport(Sport value) {
    this.sport = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the mostFavored property.
 * 
 */
public boolean isMostFavored() {
    return mostFavored;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the mostFavored property.
 * 
 */
public void setMostFavored(boolean value) {
    this.mostFavored = value;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Game` class on the server and client?

Comment: I've just added them to my original question. Unfortunately I needed to delete part of the stak trace - post too long...

Comment: Stack traces in this sort of situation are usually eminently trimmable; they tend to be extremely long and with very few interesting frames in them.

Comment: You can always put extremely long stack traces on pastebin and link them here :) Also, what might help you in this case is to do some wire-level tracking, to see what the actual xml being sent back from the Server is. If you are in Eclipse, you could try the TCP/IP Monitor View.

Comment: Also, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2623199/473637) post, it might help.

Comment: I found a solution for that a few days ago, see the end of the initially post.

Comment: please post the solution as an answer (and accept it). This is better than an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a few days ago that it had something to do with @ManyToOne and @ManyToMany JPA annotations. However, I am not sure why it fails while using those annotations, the @XmlTransient annotation resolved it. After that I simply needed to wirte some extra code for getting related objects by id.